# Extend table-cell to take up all space

Tags: html, css

This is the usual question of how to extend a div to take up all space available. The only specialty that this is a div with display table-cell.
See http://jsfiddle.net/djx9zx47/1/

```
<div class="col col-a">
  <div class="cell cell-a">
    <div>Last Login</div>
  </div>
  <div id="last_login" class="cell cell-b">
     Jan-05-2015 05:02:03 GMT
  </div>
</div>  
<div class="col col-b">
  <div class="cell cell-c">
    <div>Login Status</div>
  </div>
  <div id="login_status" class="cell cell-d">
     Active
  </div>
</div>

.cell-a {
    font-weight: bold;
    width:130px;
}
.cell-b {
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I would like to have the second columns to take up all the space they have available.

I have checked all other questions about getting the div to take up all space, but none has worked, I assume because of the display:table-cell.

EDIT (to clarify):
I mean making cell-b and cell-d to take up all the space available available.

EDIT2: call-a must keep its fixed width, so just setting cell-b to 100% doesn't solve it

Comment: Which columns ? You mean divs with class `col-b`?

Comment: Sorry, no, I mean cell-b and cell-d. I go and edit the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should reorganize the markup slightly, adding a wrap (as another table) around the cells. It will then become `table > table-row > table-cell`, and `table > table-cell`.

I also simplified your css a little bit. See the follows.

```css
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.col {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: .5em;
    border: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
.cell-a, .cell-c {
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-a">
            <div class="table"> <!-- <= this is new-->
                <div class="cell cell-a">
                    <div>Last Login</div>
                </div>
                <div class="cell cell-b" id="last_login">Jan-05-2015 05:02:03 GMT</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-b">
            <div class="table"> <!-- <= this is new-->
                <div class="cell cell-c">
                    <div>Login Status</div>
                </div>
                <div class="cell cell-d" id="login_status">Active</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/9sge8mxe/

Comment: Thanks, yes, this solves the problem presented here. Unfortunately in my specific case this did not work, because it interferes with another requirement I had (responsive design, cell-c to fold under cell-a under 50em). In any case, as this is a solution to the problem presented, I have accepted this as the right answer.

Comment: @ZoltanFedor that would be the job of media queries.

Comment: That's what I had in the rest of the css running on .col setting it's float to none, but as I have added the additional div with "table" class it didn't fold anymore. Probably because using the same "table" or something else. In any case I went with Fares' solution below, as that didn't require the reworking of the media queries.

Comment: @ZoltanFedor i don't really understand what the problem is, do you want to have col-b goes under col-a on small screen? like this? http://jsfiddle.net/9sge8mxe/1/

Answer (score 2):

If I unterstand well what you're looking for, you can make the width of `.cell-b` and `.cell-d` to `100%`:

```
.cell-b, cell-d{
    width:100%!important;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djx9zx47/5/)

**Update**
To keep the width of the first cell `.cell-a`, if you have always the content wrapped inside a second div, so you can add this:

```
.cell-a > div {
   width: 130px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that would make cell-a to loose its fix width (130px)

Comment: Thanks, this actually worked in my scenario (having responsive design for cell-c folding under cell-a under a certain width).

Answer (score 1):

Add this style:

```
.col {
  display: table;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hheyoehp/)